# Insert state and selected values at same time

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

**Table User**

```
|_id, | login |
---------------
|  1  |  test |
```

**Table Role**

```
|_id, | role_name|
------------------
|  1  |  Admin   |
|  2  | Moderator|
|  3  |  User    |
```

**Table User_Login**

`| user_id | role_id |`

I want to set for user with ID 1 roles that are searched in query by they names, here what I got so far:

```
"INSERT INTO user_role
        + "(userId, roleId) VALUES (1, (SELECT r._id FROM roles r WHERE r.role_name IN ('Admin', 'Moderator', 'User')))"
```

Thing is that is set only one Id from role instead of 3

Expected result:

```
|user_id|role_id|
-----------------
|   1   |   1   |
|   1   |   2   |
|   1   |   3   |
```

And what I get:

```
|user_id|role_id|
-----------------
|   1   |   1   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does using `insert . . . select` fix your problem?

```
INSERT INTO user_role(userId, roleId) 
    SELECT 1, r._id
    FROM roles r
    WHERE r.role_name IN ('Admin', 'Moderator', 'User');
```

It is possible that the `role_name`s do not match what is in the `IN` list.  Perhaps you should just run the subquery and see what you get.

Comment: It's really clever to use *INSERT INTO SELECT*, it is efficient and reduce an overhead!